# Solution for Dynamic Variable Type In Java

Tags: java, spring, list, generics

What is the best approach to handling this scenario. The Helper method constructor will be given various types depending on the controller methods calling the Helper method. So getMethodOne calls the helper method and provides a type argument of typeone. However the Helper method's List generic type gives an unknown class error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/methodOne", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<?> getMethodOne(){

    return Helper(typeone);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/methodTwo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<?> getMethodTwo(){

    return Helper(typetwo);
}


private List<?> Helper(type){
    // type in List<type> - gives unknown class error
    new List<type> someObject = new ArrayList<type>();

    return someObject;
}
```

I have tried an IType interface that is implemented by typeone and typetwo objects and then in the helper method updated the argument as follows

```
    private List<Itype> Helper(IType type){

    new List<type> someObject = new ArrayList<type>();

    return someObject;
}
```

Comment: your syntax of generic constructor is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be more like

```
private <T> List<T> Helper(Clazz<T> clazz){ // if you need that at all here
    List<T> someObject = new ArrayList<T>();

    return someObject;
}
```